# How to replace a string (characters and numbers)

Tags: linux, sed

I would like to replace rs101 to rs102, however it shows unterminated "s" command with this.

```
sed -i 's/rs101/rs102' file.name.
```

Is there any other solution ?

Comment: Syntax is : `s/regexp/replacement/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert `/` after rs102 .

```
sed -i 's/rs101/rs102/' file.name.
```

Syntax for Search and Replace:

```
sed 's/search/replace/' file.name
```